# Is that possible two different headers be set?

Tags: php, security, http-headers, ip

I'm getting user's IP like this:

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

My code works fine if always one of those header be set. Otherwise what happens when `$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'] = real IP` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = real ip` ? Based on the order of my conditions, `$ip` will be the *fake ip*.

So I want to know always one of those will be set or might multiple of them?

Comment: Maybe one, maybe all. Who knows? Depends on the client, the server and everything in between.

Comment: @rjdown So my code is wrong? I mean which one is the user's IP? It may be each of them, right? So should I store all of them separately?

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR is the most reliable, but it's not reliable. I'm sure that didn't help at all, that's how it is though. Store any that are set.

Comment: @rjdown `:-)` Overall what's the best approach to get user's IP?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php and take note of all the warnings...!